# Change key value in Python 3 dictionary using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dictionary

Given the following dictionary, how can I return new keys that strip away all non-numbers from the keys?

```
import re 

dict {'abc_12': 5, 'abc_1': 7, 'abc_34': 10}

for k in dict:
    re.sub('[^0-9]', '', k)
    # change value of first key to '12': 5
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys.  How do you want to handle that issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to replace the actual dictionary keys with new ones with all non-numeric characters removed.

The easiest way to do that would simply be to create a new dictionary:

```
new_dict = {re.sub('[^0-9]', '', k): v for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

but if for some reason you absolutely need to preserve the existing one, you would need to `pop` each value and insert a new key with the existing value. You'd need to make sure you're operating on a static copy of the keys, otherwise the iteration would include the new values you've inserted and you'd get into all sorts of trouble.

```
for k in list(dict.keys()):
    v = my_dict.pop(k)
    new_k = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', k)
    my_dict[new_k] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're best off creating a new dictionary:

```
old_dict = {'abc_12': 5, 'abc_1': 7, 'abc_34': 10}

new_dict = {re.sub('[^0-9]', '', key): old_dict[key] for key in old_dict}
```

Comment: are you sure that you're iterating over keys in that loop?

Comment: Pretty sure - `for key in dict` iterates over the keys of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You do not *need* a regex:

```
>>> di={'abc_12': 5, 'abc_1': 7, 'abc_34': 10}
>>> {''.join(c for c in k if c in '0123456789'):v for k, v in di.items()}
{'1': 7, '12': 5, '34': 10}
```